# Custom Status Bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Необходим Custom Status Bar. Обладаю хорошим туториолом ка изменить цвет, но не знаю как его сделать изначально. Суть в том, что ребята сделали синий статус бар по умолчанию. Изучение их кода ни к чему не привело. Подскажите как мне иго включить! =)

[image]

P.S.  [туториал по смене цвета тут](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-bar-back-butto/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить в свойствах NavigationController свойство Global Tint

[image]